# High-order function "every" method PROBLEM

Tags: javascript, eloquent

I have a problem to solve in **ELOQUENTJS** book, can somebody help and tell me what's wrong in this code.

This is my code so far.

```js
function every(array, test) {
  for (let i of array) {
    let curArr = array[i];
    if (test(curArr)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

console.log(every([1, 3, 4, 12], n => n < 10));
// returns true
```

I'm expecting to see false as a return, but somehow it returns true.

Comment: You immediately return a value after the first test.

Comment: `.every` exists in JS : `[1, 3, 4, 12].every(n => n < 10) // false`

Comment: @JeremyThille: note that this is an exercise from a book.  It's probably good practice to try to write such built-in functions from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is with your `return true`. This line will make your function "exit", thus stopping any of the remaining code from executing. As `1 < 10`, you are immediately returning true from your function. Instead, you can `return true` only once you have checked every element.

Your other issue is that a `for..of` loop will get every element in your array, not every *index* like you think you're doing so `i` infact actually is equal to your `curArr` variable:

```js
function every(array, test) {
  for(let curArr of array){
    if(!test(curArr)){
      return false;
    } 
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(every([1, 3, 4, 12], n => n < 10));
```

Comment: it returns false when i change ARRAY to console.log(every([1, 3, 4], n => n < 10));       Why is that happening. It should return true.

Comment: @sencho I've updated my answer, its because `for .. of` will give you every element in your array, so `i` isn't the index, but rather an element

Comment: oh i see it now. Thanks!

Comment: @sencho no worries :)